# What is called the "area size that an animal usually lives in"?

Tags: zoology, ecology, population-biology, nomenclature

What is called the "area size that an animal usually lives in" or "needs for a normal life"? Is there any specific term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid confusion I just want to add to fileunderwater's answer the equivalent words we use to describe the "area size a population/species lives in".

The spatial range a single individual occupies is generally called `home range` or `territory` (as fileunderwater said before me).

The spatial range a single species (or population) occupies is called `geographic range` or `species range` and we call the boundaries of this range the `geographic range limits` or sometimes called `range limits` only.

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for '[Home range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_range)' (see also the definition in [Encyclopaedia Britannica](http://global.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/270112/home-range))? Generally, 'home range' is defined as the entire area an individual animal uses, while the '[territory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territory_%28animal%29)' is the subset of the home range that is actually defended from conspecifics (in animals that show territoriality). 'Home range' is often delimited by the types of environments used and movement patterns of individuals.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps also [Habitat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitat).

> The term typically refers to the zone in which the organism lives and
>   where it can find food, shelter, protection and mates for
>   reproduction...